# selenium - find element by class name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure if im using the right method to click what i'm trying to click right now.
I am trying to click on 'battling' and then subsequently the appropriate type of animal to kill after that.

```
import autogui, sys, time, webbrowser, selenium
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Open Browser and visit website.
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.iqrpg.com/game.html')
time.sleep(5)

#Complete username and password fields + Login
userN = 'seltest'
passW = 'seltest'
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login_username").send_keys(userN)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login_password").send_keys(passW + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
#find Battling and click to begin fight
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("Battling")).Click();
```

The inspect element for what i am trying to click on is as follows:

```
<a data-v-ae2d03a4="" href="/areas" class="">Battling</a>
```

typeerror: str object is not callable

tried a lot of out dated and in date web element searches, i've also tried calling upon 'a', 'area's, the link itself to /areas, a tonne of stuff, i just dont know what i'm doing it seems

Comment: `<a data-v-ae2d03a4="" href="/areas" class="">Battling</a>` From what I can see, the class is "", whereas the `text` is Battling

Answer (score 0):

`Battling` is not a class name. It's a text content.
You can locate that element by following ways:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Battling')]")).click()
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='/areas']")).click()
```

Also, dont mix other languages styles. I see all your code here is in Python while `.Click();` is `C#` style...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, with `By.LINK_TEXT`:

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT('Battling')).click()
```

The error `'str' object is not callable` appear because this line code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("Battling")).Click();
```

It's wrong patterrn to find element method in python style.